# Refactoring in Java: The method setCode(int) in the type Refactor is not applicable for the arguments ()

Tags: java, refactoring, code-duplication

I'm trying to reduce code duplication by creating a new class (Refactor.java) to accommodate the methods that are called in two other classes (A and B).

This is what I came up with so far:

```
public class Refactor {
protected int code; // code
protected String companyName; // company name
protected String email; // email of the company
protected String type; // type
protected double price; // price

// gets and sets
public int getCode() {
    return code;
}
public void setCode(int c) {
    this.code = c;
}
public String getCompanyName(){
    return companyName;
}
public void setCompanyName(String cn) {
    this.companyName = cn;
}
public String getEmail(){
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String em) {
    this.email = em;
}
public String getType(){
    return type;
}
public void setType(String t) {
    this.type = t;
}
public double getPrice(){
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(double p) {
    this.price = p;
}
}
```

In class A, the "accData.getSomething()" methods seem to be okay, but all "accData.setSomething()" methods give me the following error: "The method setCode(int) in the type Refactor is not applicable for the arguments ()".

This is what I have on class A so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Accommodation
{
    protected static int MAX_NUM_TOURS = 3; // maximum number of tours defined by the hotel regulation bodies

    protected int code; // code
    protected String companyName; // company name
    protected String email; // email of the company
    protected String type; // type
    protected double price; // price
    protected String city;  // city of the accommodation
    protected int numberBeds; // number of beds

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param c code
     * @param cn company name
     * @param em email of the company
     * @param t type (hotel, hostel, bnb, ...)
     * @param p price
     * @param ct city of the accommodation
     * @param nb number of beds
     */

    public Accommodation(int c, String cn, String em, String t, double p, String ct, int nb) {
        this.code = c;
        this.companyName = cn;
        this.email = em;
        this.type = t;
        this.price = p; 
        this.city = ct;
        this.numberBeds = nb;
    }

    
    //this is where I'm trying to call the Refactor class
    public static void AccData() {
        Refactor accData = new Refactor();
        accData.getCode();
        accData.setCode();
        accData.getCompanyName();
        accData.setCompanyName();
        accData.getEmail();
        accData.setEmail();
        accData.getType();
        accData.setType();
        accData.getPrice();
        accData.setPrice();

    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public int getNumberBeds() {
        return numberBeds;
    }
    public void setNumberBeds(int numberBeds) {
        this.numberBeds = numberBeds;
    }
}
```

Why am I getting that error? How can I fix this?

I tried googling on how to refactor code and found [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53229324/how-to-refactor-two-classes-with-very-similar-methods-but-using-different-types) which is similar to mine. I however didn't quite understand the answers given, hence why I am asking again.

I'm expecting to be able to avoid code duplication by calling on these methods from class Refactor.

Comment: If you want to use methods from `Refactor` class you need to extend the class from `Accomodation` like this `public class Accommodation extends Refactor`

Answer (score 0):

if you have a class like this:

```
class A {
    // ...
    public void setCode(int param) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

you can call the method setCode like this:

```
A a = new A();
a.setCode(1);
a.setCode(2);
```

but you can't call the method setCode like this:

```
A a = new A();
a.setCode();
```

Back to your code:

```
public class Refactor {
    // ...
    public void setCode(int c) {
        this.code = c;
    }
    // ...
}

public static void AccData() {
    Refactor accData = new Refactor();
    accData.getCode();
    accData.setCode(); // here setCode need a parameter

}
```

setCode needs a parameter, and its method signature is `Refactor#setCode(int)`, but you don’t pass parameters when you call it, and the method signature you call is `Refactor#setCode(void)`